# to execute fragment when visible but not recreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have this problem:

At present I use BottomNavigationView to navigate through the fragments...

Code:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

               //Fragment fragment = null;
               Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_home);
                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.ic_home:

                        if (currentFragment instanceof MainFragment){

                            //execute code
                        }

                        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu") != null) {
                            //if the fragment exists, show it.
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu")).commit();
                            toolbar.setTitle("Flip");
                            item = menu.getItem(0);
                            item.setChecked(true);
                        } else {
                            //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container_home, new MainFragment(), "mainMenu").commit();
                            toolbar.setTitle("Flip");
                            item = menu.getItem(0);
                            item.setChecked(true);
                        }

                        //Hide Others Fragments
                        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("categories") != null){
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("categories")).commit();
                        }
                        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("feedUsers") != null){
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("feedUsers")).commit();
                        }
                        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("explore") != null){
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("explore")).commit();
                        }
                        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("opcoes") != null){
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("opcoes")).commit();
                        }

                        break;


                }

                return false;

            }
        });
```

What I need:

Run some code when clicking and the visible fragment is the menu fragment itself.

On Here:

```
if (currentFragment instanceof MainFragment){

                            //execute code
                        }
```

Can I execute some code only when the fragment reappears without being recreated?

An alternative would be to access recyclerview or send command to execute in fragment

I need to access the RecyclerView Fragment to be able to send it to the top of the screen when two clicks are in the BottomNavigationView.

Comment: what did you use to hide it ?

Comment: that: if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu") != null){                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu")).commit(); }. @MohamedEmbaby

Comment: "Can I execute some code only when the fragment reappears without being recreated?" Can't you just call the `onResume()` of the Fragment and check if it still is the same reference ?

Comment: how would I call OnResume a previously created fragment? @MohamedEmbaby

Comment: Can't you just write the code after fragmentManager.show
:- you don't call onResume its override method gets called automatically when fragment resumes.... but I really don't know if onResume is vaild option because I think fragmentmanager.hide doesn't stop activity just hide it so there is no onResume

Comment: OnResume is not calling. I tested it right now! It is called only when first created. @MohamedEmbaby

Comment: yeah as expected xD,  
Can't you just write the code after fragmentManager show ?

Comment: I do not know if I understand. How could I write a code that needs to be executed within the snippet here in the activity?Would you help me? @MohamedEmbaby

Comment: You are most likely looking for `onHiddenChanged` callback?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you there is more than one way

**First Way,**, call the code you want after you show the fragment, very easy

```
if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu") != null) {
                            //if the fragment exists, show it.
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu")).commit();
                            toolbar.setTitle("Flip");
                            item = menu.getItem(0);
                            item.setChecked(true);


                            ////////////////////////////////////
                            // execute the code you want here //
                            ////////////////////////////////////
                        }
```

**Second way** you cant set the `visibility` of the `fragment` after you show/hide it and checks the `visibility` in advance

After `fragment` show add `setVisibility` `VISIBLE`

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu")).commit();
currentFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and After `fragment` hide add `setVisibility` `GONE`

```
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("categories")).commit();
currentFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and checks wherever you want for the `Visibility` of the `fragment` by

```
if(currentFragment != null){

   if(currentFragment().getView().getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
     // fragment is shown, do some action
   }else {
     // fragment is hiden, do some action
   }

}
```

if you can't check it and have no trigger to check the `visibility` you can make a `Runnable` that check for the `Visibility` every 1 second or whatever you want....

**Third way**, very efficient. use `onResume` but `onResume` is only called if the `fragment` wasn't running unless you called it manually.

```
if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu") != null) {
                            //if the fragment exists, show it.
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainMenu")).commit();
                            toolbar.setTitle("Flip");
                            item = menu.getItem(0);
                            item.setChecked(true);

                            currentFragment().onResume();
                        }
                        //Hide Others Fragments
                        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("categories") != 
                        null){
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("categories")).commit();
                        currentFragment().onStop();

                        }
```

then

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
      // your code
    }
```

Some expeniliations for third way ;

you use this way only if your fragments were not containing values at runtime and you want to keep this values, and don't use these values in runtime except if they were `static`
exp; if you load `imageView` from `bitmap` at runtime to a certain `fragment` and you hide the `fragment`(as you did in you code) and after while you show that certain `fragment` again you will find the `imageView` because the `fragment` was running in `background`,
On the other hand if you called terminate the `fragment` and started it again you will not find the bitmap or `ImageView`. so that's the use of `onStop` method. it stops everything was in `fragment`(`bitmap` and `imageView`) and saves until `fragment` RESUME not START.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onHiddenChanged(boolean)` for this.

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean isVisible) {
   ... // handle fragment visibility change here
}
```